# cocotron - installCDT installation help

Tags: cocoa, cocotron

I'm having trouble installing the most recent installCDT. when I do `sudo ./install.sh`, it seems to go on forever and is definitely looping (checking for stuff, then installing stuff, repeat).  (If I don't have the sudo it ends after some permission denieds).  Anyone else experience this or know what's wrong? Sorry I'm a noob :<

edit: here is the output that keeps repeating after the downloads and unzipping (didn't realize I got an error before for putting it here since it was too long) http://www.scribd.com/doc/52635397/installCDToutput

Comment: The script should be spitting out a lot of information, can you provide details on which part is not ending? BTW, it does take a long time to run since it compiling gcc/binutils.Also, http://groups.google.com/group/cocotron-dev/ is a good place to ask Cocotron questions.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but there was still a way to go on that build. Those last lines in your log happen a few times in my log. The last time is only about a quarter of the way through the process.

[Here's my log.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/62614100/InstallCDT-Log) Note that it is 622 pages and yours is 12. This is the kind of thing you want to start right before you leave for lunch.